# SQL Server doesn't seem to be starting automatically after updates

Tags: sql-server

It's a pretty short problem. I've got SQL Server 2008 R2. A few days ago I downloaded Silverlight, which turned on "Updates for other Microsoft Applications," which in turn realized that Visual Studio, SQL Server, and a few other misc things had plenty of updates. I downloaded and installed them all, and now it seems that SQL Server is no longer starting up when I turn on the computer. It's still set to Automatic, and SQL Express is starting up fine. Any idea why it wouldn't be? Something interfering with it?

And to note, it works fine once I click "start."

Comment: I ran into a customer whose system started doing this after running Avast anti-virus. Turning it off allowed the service to Autostart. I gave her a shortcut to manually start it until her PC vendor fixes the issue. The SQL Browser was listed in it's firewall and started okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend changing the service from Automatic to Automatic (Delayed Start).  You can do this directly from the `Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services` area.

I've personally seen cases where something else is going on during start-up that blocks the service, but changing to Auto-Delayed fixed the symptom.  Note I used the word symptom on purpose.

The true problem should probably still be found and fixed - but testing Auto (Delayed Start) would at least help you zero in on the problem.